# Pandas: Look if items are in a list in Series.series in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I have a Dataframe that look like this (small version):

```
    A   B   C
0   125 ADB [AF:12]
1   189 ACB [AF:78, AF:85, AF:98]
2   148 ADB []
3   789 ARF [AF:89, AF:85, AF:12]
4   789 BCD [AF:76, AF:25]
```

How can I see if some of the items in column "C" are in a list?
knowing that when I do type(df.C) I get  `class 'pandas.core.series.Series'`

if for example the list is:

```
['AF:12', 'AF25']
```

The expected output would be:

```
    A   B   C                        D
0   125 ADB [AF:12]                  True
1   189 ACB [AF:78, AF:85, AF:98]    False
2   148 ADB []                       False
3   789 ARF [AF:89, AF:85, AF:12]    True
4   789 BCD [AF:76, AF:25]           True
```

I have tried `df['D'] = df['C'].isin(list)`
but get False everywhere probably because "C" is a list of list.

Is there a way to get around that?

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: What is the type of `df['C']` ? try `type(df['C'][0])` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data = {'B':['ADB','ACB','ADB','ARF','BCD'],
        'A':[125,189,148,789,789],
        'C':[['AF:12'],['AF:78', 'AF:85', 'AF:98'],[],
        ['AF:89', 'AF:85', 'AF:12'],['AF:76', 'AF:25']]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

def in_list(list_to_search,terms_to_search):
    results = [item for item in list_to_search if item in terms_to_search]
    if len(results) > 0:
        return 'True'
    else:
        return 'False'

df['D'] = df['C'].apply(lambda x: in_list(x, ['AF:12', 'AF:25']))
```

Result:

```
     A    B                      C      D
0  125  ADB                [AF:12]   True
1  189  ACB  [AF:78, AF:85, AF:98]  False
2  148  ADB                     []  False
3  789  ARF  [AF:89, AF:85, AF:12]   True
4  789  BCD         [AF:76, AF:25]   True
```

Comment: Thanks, looks like working for me!
This function is of great help to handle series of series

Answer (score 4):

If the type of elements of `C` column is `list` , then I believe one method to do this would be to use `set` intersection between your list and the elements of `C` column using [`Series.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.apply.html) method . Example -

```
setlst = set(yourlist)
df['D'] = df['C'].apply(lambda x: bool(setlst.intersection(x)))
```

You can confirm that `C` is of type list, if `type(df['C'][0])` is `list` .

Also please note using list as a variable name is not recommended as it would shadow the built in type `list` .

Comment: I will try that as well thanks. And keep in mind the advice.

Answer (score 0):

```
def is_in_list():
    for ele in df['C']:
    if ele in list:
        return True
    return False;
```

Maybe this function can make it.